# How to pass <div> value to another Controller in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have **Home** and **Customer** controller

**Home Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return view()
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="card" data-csid="jieg83ndks90">

</div>
```

> When user click on above div it will redirect to **Customer.cshtml** on **CustomerController**, and also it has to get the div `data-csid` value(jieg83ndks90)

**CustomerController**

```
public ActionResult Customer()
{
    return view()
}
```

> Note: I want to redirect from **index.cshtml** to **Customer.cshtml** and pass the value(jieg83ndks90) also to **Customer.cshtml**

Comment: How exactly are you redirecting the user?  You can include the value on that redirect and receive the value in your controller action method.

Comment: @David can you check update please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking several things:

- How to handle a click event in JavaScript
- How to get a data-* value in JavaScript
- How to redirect in JavaScript
- How to include a value on a URL
- How to receive a value in an action method

Let's start with the first one, a click event.  Since you're getting started with ASP.NET MVC, I'm going to assume jQuery is included in the project template.  So a click event might look something like this:

```
$('div.card').on('click', function () {

});
```

This would invoke that (currently empty) function any time a user clicks on a `<div>` with `class="card"`.  In that function you want to grab the value of the data-* attribute of the `<div>` which was clicked:

```
$('div.card').on('click', function () {
    let csid = $(this).data('csid');
});
```

Now you want to redirect to a URL and include that value.  There are a variety of ways to build a URL in ASP.NET MVC and some have interesting workarounds when used in JavaScript.  But let's keep it simple.  Use the `Url.Action` helper, and remember to wrap it in quotes in JavaScript since it's a string:

```
$('div.card').on('click', function () {
    let csid = $(this).data('csid');
    let url = '@Url.Action("Customer", "Customer")';
});
```

(You are encouraged to look at the page source in your browser to see what this generated.)  And you can add the value to the query string of the URL this generates:

```
$('div.card').on('click', function () {
    let csid = $(this).data('csid');
    let url = '@Url.Action("Customer", "Customer")' + '?csid=' + csid;
});
```

Then use that URL to [redirect the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage):

```
$('div.card').on('click', function () {
    let csid = $(this).data('csid');
    let url = '@Url.Action("Customer", "Customer")' + '?csid=' + csid;
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

**Important Note:** The difference may seem unimportant, but understanding the semantics of what's going on is *very* important.  You are *not* redirecting the user to `Customer.cshtml`.  You are redirecting the user to the *action method* on the controller.  When that action method returns a view, that *view* will be `Customer.cshtml`.

This becomes important when you want to use the value that's on the query string.  Since the user is going to the action method, get that value in the action method:

```
public ActionResult Customer(string csid)
{
    return View();
}
```

Now obviously the question becomes... What do you plan to *do* with that `csid` value.  This is pretty much where the context of your question ends.  At this point you've redirected the user with the value, how you use that value is up to you.  If you want to pass it from the controller action to the view then the standard approach would be to set the value on a model that you pass to your view.  For example:

```
public ActionResult Customer(string csid)
{
    var model = new SomeViewModel { CSID = csid };
    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view you would put this line at the top to bind to that model:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

From there you can access `Model.CSID` wherever you want in your view.